# Hot to show only two digits after decimal using double

Tags: java, android, double

I use:

```
priceTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f",price));
```

price is double. It works but when I have to retrieve the value from the TextView and convert it to double I get the following error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1,2"

Is there another way to do the same thing and avoid the error?

Here is the code complete:

```
Double prezzoDouble = Double.parseDouble(this.prezzo);
prezzoTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", prezzoDouble));

quantitaSceltaEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    String prezzoUnitario=prezzo;

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        int quantitaSceltaInt = Integer.parseInt(quantitaSceltaEditText.getText().toString());

        if(quantitaSceltaInt>=1) {
            String prezzoTotale = String.valueOf(String.format ("%.2f", (calcoloPrezzoTotale())));
            prezzoTextView.setText(prezzoTotale);
        }
        else
        {
            prezzoTextView.setText(prezzoUnitario);
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    private double calcoloPrezzoTotale()
    {
        double prezzoNum=Double.parseDouble(prezzoTextView.getText().toString()); ///////////
        double prezzoTotale=0;

        int quantitaSceltaNum = Integer.parseInt(quantitaSceltaEditText.getText().toString());

        prezzoTotale = prezzoNum * quantitaSceltaNum;

        return prezzoTotale;
    }
});
```

Comment: That's because you are trying to retrieve two numbers at a time it looks like.

Comment: How could I solve it?

Comment: Post your code that produces the error.

Comment: @Ptr Do you use a comma `,` instead of a dot `.` as decimal separator?

Comment: "*No, I use a dot*" take a look at what value you want to parse: `"Invalid double: "1,2"`...

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(...)` is the opposite of `Double.toString()`, which has nothing to do with locale dependent number formatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the double assigned in line

```
prezzoTotale = String.valueOf(String.format ("%.2f", (calcoloPrezzoTotale())));
```

contains a comma (`,`, i.e. `1,2`) due to the locale settings. So take care that parsing happens with the same locale.

Class [`NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) helps you out:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("1,234");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

Looking at your code it could be `Locale.ITALY` as well ;) check the full Locale list [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

***p.s.***: `String.format()` uses `Locale.getDefault();` as per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). Use logcat to check its value, if you are not sure about the system setting or use the alternative method `public static String format(Locale l, String format, Object... args)` which allows you to specify the Locale.

Comment: I see this in the logcat D/it_IT

Comment: Ok, so using `NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);` should give you the right value without any `NumberFormatException`'s :) or even better: use `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());` for consistency ...

Comment: I've used NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);

Comment: Instead of getting invalid double "1,2"  now is invalid double "1,20"

Comment: Though I was pretty sure about the answer, I made a small test and it works as expected . Seems you have another issue. Do you still use `parseDouble()` somewhere (this might cause this exception as well)?

Comment: I've solved it, I made a mistake to change my code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
String.format("%.2f",price) //String.format("%2.f",price) is wrong
```

or

```
Double.parseDouble(this.prezzo);
```

could be a problem decimal separator in this.prezzo, according to the configuration can be a point or comma

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you live you could use the Locale.setDefault(Locale) method to change the jvm default which appears to be the issue. It's setDefault (Locale aLocale). This sets a systemwide resource. As per Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```java
double dTotalPrice = 4.5;
String totalPrice = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(dTotalPrice);
```